# How to create a LWPolyline using pyautocad

Tags: python

When I try to use pyautocad to create a light weight polyline, it tried several different ways to fill in the points arguments. But everytime what I got was

> "File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\automation.py", line 729,
>   in _invoke
>       dp, var, None, argerr)
>   _ctypes.COMError: (-2147352567, '发生意外。', (None, None, None, 0, None))"

Here are my codings:

```
from pyautocad import *

acad = Autocad()
p = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4]
pl = acad.model.AddLightWeightPolyline(p)

from pyautocad import *

acad = Autocad()
p1 = APoint(0, 0)
p2 = APoint(10, 10)
p3 = APoint(20, 10)
pl = acad.model.AddLightWeightPolyline(p1, p2, p3)
```

None of these would work. Could anybody tell me the reason? Thanks a lot.

And also I'm new to programming, so it's highly appreciated if anyone could tell me how to find some reference or methods built in pyautocad so that I can learn some basic myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the solution:

import array

p = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4] # Change the integers to double, ie, 1.1, 1.1, etc.

pl = acad.model.AddLightWeightPolyline(array.array("d", p))

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Felipe. It did work. Would like where did you find the solution? I searched pyautocad website the help document was really rare. Could you give me some suggestions on python programming learning sources. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using pyautocad types:

```
from pyautocad import Autocad, aDouble

acad = Autocad()
p = aDouble(0,0,10,10,20,10)
pl = acad.model.AddLightWeightPolyline(p)
```

In this video is explained, but it's in Spanish: [VIDEO EXPLANATION](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATfxWBX7YbQ&t=112s)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please ensure your answer is complete on its own. Instead of linking to a (Spanish) video explanation add a textual explanation here yourself. External resources may become unavailable at any time. So include external resources only ever as references, and not as required parts to understand your answer. – Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).